# Visual Studio 2010 Add .NET References Missing / No Assemblies

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, registry, .net-assembly, .net-framework-version

I am facing a weird problem with Visual Studio 2010. It all started when I installed VS Community & then uninstalled it. After uninstalling the VS Community I understood that I am no more having any of my class libraries / projects on version 4.0 of .NET framework.

Moreover, In target framework, I am not also able to see the name of the .NET framework.

I checked on internet and installed standalone complete installation of .NET framework 4.0 but I was still not able to see .NET framework in Target Framework list in project properties.

Then, I added .NET framework entry in the XML from where Target framework list is populated.

After doing so, I was getting all reference not found errors in my projects. On checking the "Add Reference", I found that there are no more assemblies for .NET to be referenced in program.

Can someone please suggest what should be done in such case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you uninstalled Community, you surely also lost the reference assemblies.  They are stored in c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies.  Re-installing VS2010 is the obvious fix.

Comment: Thanks Hans!! Seems OK after re-installation!!